# MS Azure WebApplication MONITOR - chart API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

This may be a silly question but here we go: "Is there a way to access the Azure WebApp MONITOR Chart (see below) and embed it into my website?".

[image]

Comment: I don`t think we have such feature that provide embedded chart. but sounds like a good thing to have. Why not create a feature ask in here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal

Answer (score 1):

**Azure Insights REST API** provides Microsoft Azure Insights operations using Resource Manager. Insights includes a unified API to retrieve **monitoring metrics** and operational events for all of the Azure resources that are available in Azure Resource Manager.

[Azure Insights REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx)

For C# .NET SDK for Azure Insights, you can look into: Microsoft Azure Insights Library

[Microsoft Azure Insights Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Insights/)

Comment: hi, yes, I found that one but it does not seem to look the same and provide the same graphical presentation